# Permutations: an even number of 5 digits not starting with 0

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am having difficulties understanding how to solve this:

If we have a set of 7 numbers A = {0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8 ,9 } and we draw 5 numbers randomly to create a 5 digit number that cannot start by 0 and with no repetitions. How many of those numbers will be even?

Comment: If you want to count how many numbers meet your conditions, you do not draw the digits randomly.  It helps to state the question accurately.  Do you want the fraction of the five digit numbers that are even or the count of five digit numbers that meet the restrictions?

Comment: @jyre:  having chosen the units digit first the number of choices for the first digit depends on whether the units digit is zero or not.

Comment: It looks like 3/7 will be even.

Comment: @herbsteinberg:  that is not correct because $0$ is not allowed to be the leading digit, so is more likely to be available for the units place.

Comment: The numbers with $0$ in the units can have any of the $6$ digits $1,4,5,7,8,9$ in the first digits, any of the $5$ remaining in the second, and so on. That makes $6\times5\times4\times 3$ numbers. The numbers that don't have $0$ in the units can have there $4$ or $8$. And then $5$ choices for the first digit, $4$ for the second and so on. That is $2\times5\times4\times3\times2$. Therefore, the total is $6\times5\times4\times 3 + 2\times5\times4\times3\times2$.

Comment: Ignore previous comment by me.        To get fraction, there are 2 terms depending on whether the first digit is even or odd.  If it is even, then the last digit has a probability of 1/3 of being even.  If the first term is odd, the least digit has a probability of 1/2 of being even.  Net result the probability of last term being even is $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{4}{9}$.

Comment: To Ross Millikan.  I became aware of my error soon afterwards, but it was too late to erase the comment.  I added a second comment with the correction.

Comment: Your question is unclear:  Do you wish to count the number of five-digit even numbers that can be formed by selecting numbers from set $A$ without repetition or, as your use of the word randomly suggests, find the probability that a five-digit number formed by selecting numbers from set $A$ without repetition is even?

Comment: To N. F. Tausig:  I believe the question assumes each digit selection has an equal probability, with the exception of 0 not being first.